# Cannot show View on gesture tapped in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeList: View {
    @State private var show: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< 5) { item in
                    CourseView()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.show.toggle()
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: self.$show) {ContentView()}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeList()
    }
}
```

When I tap on the CourseView I want it to show `ContentView()` but it doesn't work.
I don't know why.

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be only one sheet in body, so

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< 5) { item in
                CourseView()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.show.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$show) {ContentView()} // move it here !!
}
```